# Why am I seeing this Springboot starter 2.1.2 pom non-parsable issue?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have been battling with Spring for a couple of hours trying to get it to parse a pom file. Using spring's initilzr I created a projected with the required dependencies as can be seen in the pom below. I have checked it against a xml formatter and everything seems fine however it doesn't want to compile giving the error:

> Non-parseable POM /Users/mel22/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.1.2.RELEASE.pom: Expected root element 'project' but found 'html'

I have tried mutliple things including deleting my .m2/repository, mvn clean install/package.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.ellismatt</groupId>
<artifactId>springrestapi</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>springrestapi</name>
<description>Spring REST Api project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Comment: Wow.  That's a strange one.  I didn't see a problem with your pom, but I created a test just to be sure, and it works fine for me.  So it must be something in your environment.  Have you looked at the actual parent pom file to make sure it isn't somehow corrupted even after killing your .m2/repository ?  I'm even on a Mac, like you :)

Comment: @Steve So the .pom file inside the parent pom seems to be html, any idea why this is or how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That one bit:

> Expected root element 'project' but found 'html'

...reminds me of a really tricky issue I once saw.  Are you in a corporate environment that uses Artifactory or Nexus or something similar for caching of resources?  It's possible that there's a firewall issue resulting in your repository cache solution getting a "this website has been blocked" page and treating it as if it were the POM.

Try opening the relevant POM file from your .m2 directory in a text editor to see if it looks it might be HTML being returned from your firewall.

This exact thing happened to me once with Artifactory (but it was a JAR file for a dependency, and not a POM).

Comment: Looking at the pom file its referring to, it seems to be pulling from a corporate nexus repo to which im outside the network, could this potentially be the issue then?

Comment: @Matt If you have Maven configured to pull from Nexus, and you're outside of the network (and not on the VPN), that very well could be causing the issue.  I'd suggest either hopping on the VPN (if applicable), or temporarily renaming your `~/.m2/settings.xml` file to prevent any local setting that are redirecting you to the corporate Nexus (just be sure to change it back when you're in the office!)

Comment: Yeah im on corporate vpn now,  i changed the settings.xml name for now and that seems to have worked. Cheers for the help! :)

Comment: Also website may be down. Currently https://code.lds.org is not available and returns html